# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath not triggered unless touch moves slightly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a container ViewController that loads within it UITableView using the container View object and an embed segue in my storyboard. I'm having an issue inside of that tableView where the cells don't trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method unless I touch and just give it a little drag or touch with two fingers.

My tableCell Views are subclasses of UITableCellView that do contain an image, a background view, etc, but I've ensured that all of those subviews are set to no userInteraction. The same cells loaded into another tableview work fine.

One thing I notice is that that selection highlight for the cell flashes on and off when touched, vs remaining selected.

I've tried every imaginable permutation of scrolling options and selection settings on my tableView.

What on earth could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Try disabling multitouch in the storyboard menu for the cell and table, this can cause the side effect of forcing you to make additional movements to trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but this hasn't helped. I've tried editing values both in storyboard and tableview/cell.multipleTouchEnabled = false in code with not change. But I have noticed it works everytime if I touch with two fingers.

Answer (score 0):

You may have embedded your table view within a scroll view. This can cause the behavior you're seeing.